# Why Delphi "for" acting like that?

Tags: delphi

Delphi XE2, simple code:

```
function FastSwap(Value: uint16): uint16; register; overload;
asm
  bswap eax
  shr eax, 16
end;
...
type
  PPicEleHdr = ^TPicEleHdr;

  TPicEleHdr = packed record
    zero, size, count: word;
  end;
var
  count: integer;
  buf: TBytes;
begin
...
  peh := @buf[offs];
  count := integer(FastSwap(peh.count));
  for i := 0 to count - 1 do begin
```

and here at `for` I see in CPU window

```
UnitExtract.pas.279: for i := 0 to count - 1 do begin
0051E459 8B45DC           mov eax,[ebp-$24]
0051E45C 48               dec eax
0051E45D 85C0             test eax,eax
0051E45F 0F82CD000000     jb $0051e532
0051E465 40               inc eax
0051E466 8945AC           mov [ebp-$54],eax
0051E469 C745F400000000   mov [ebp-$0c],$00000000
```

so when count is `0` nothing works properly, `test eax, eax` (eax = $FFFFFFFF after `dec eax`) not affecting Carry flag while `jb` acting by Carry flag.
Is there something I don't understand about using `for`?

Comment: FWIW this question would have been easier to answer if you had provided complete code. In this case Mason and I were able to infer from the asm that your integer is unsigned. However, it's always better to provide a complete program, as short as possible.

Comment: Whole source is quite big: extracting bonus data from `tiff` files from folder, but answers below was useful.

Comment: Yes, of course the whole source is big. That's why you cut it down to a complete compilable 10 line sample. That's all you need to demonstrate this issue. It always pays to do that.

Comment: By the way, byteswapping of 16bit operand can be done easier and faster with `xchg    al, ah`

Comment: -1. You ask why the loop acts "like that" and then say "nothing works." You need to be more specific. *Describe* how the loop acts. *Tell* what it means for the program to "work" properly. You ask if there's "something" you don't understand; there probably is, but you need to state what *your* understanding is before anyone can be certain that you're missing something.

Comment: Isn't that obvious if `for i:=0; count - 1 do` where count is 0 `nothing works properly` only possible if code execution going inside loop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By a process of reverse engineering, I infer that `i` is an unsigned 32 bit integer, `Cardinal`. So the compiler performs the `for` loop arithmetic in an unsigned context. This means that `Count-1` is interpreted as unsigned, and so your loop runs from `0` to `high(i)`.

To flesh this out, this is what happens step by step:

- `Count` is `$00000000`.
- `Count-1` is evaluated and has value `$FFFFFFFF`.
- Interpreted as an unsigned integer `$FFFFFFFF` is 2<sup>32</sup>-1.
- Your loop body executes for all values 0 <= i < 2<sup>32</sup>.

The solution is to make your loop variable be a signed integer, for example `Integer`.

When you switch `i` to be of type `Integer`, the following happens:

- `Count` is `$00000000`.
- `Count-1` is evaluated and has value `$FFFFFFFF`.
- Interpreted as a signed integer `$FFFFFFFF` is -1.
- The loop body does not execute.

Comment: Also thanks, unfortunately I can't mark 2 messages as answer.

Comment: But you don't have to chose Mason's!!  ;-)  And that was absolutely meant as a joke!!!!   Do choose whichever you prefer.

Comment: Ok :) your answer more extended :) I was thinking compiler deciding by `count` type (I had such issues before: compiler ignores things like `v := byte(someint);`) so do not paid enough attention to `i` type.

Comment: Yes, it's the type of the loop variable that matters. I remember learning this the hard way when porting a codebase from Modula-2 which used 1-based indices, to Delphi 1 and using 0-based indices. It was not pretty and I hit your very problem time after time. I was a slow learner back then and SO did not exist!!

Answer (score 7):

As written, this won't compile, since you don't have a declaration for `i`.

But my psychic debugging senses say that `i` is declared somewhere as a `cardinal` (unsigned integer), and thus when it tries to evaluate `0 - 1`, it gets `MAXINT` instead of `-1`, because unsigned integers can't represent negative values.

You should never use unsigned integers as either the index variable or the bounding variables of a `for` loop if there's any chance at all that they can go negative.  Otherwise, you get errors like this.  In fact, you should probably just not use unsigned integers in general.  They're not as useful as they look (if you need a value higher than the maximum signed value for a size, it's likely that you'll end up needing a value higher than twice that at some point, so what you really need is the next larger integer size) and they tend to cause strange bugs like this one.